# Как передать value ссылки в значение style другого объекта на JS?

Tags: javascript

есть список ссылок:

```
<ul id="colors">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" value="background-color: #red;">Красный</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" value="background-color: #green;">Зеленый</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" value="background-color: #black;">Черный</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

и есть объект:

```
<div style="width:100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью JS сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, к объекту добавлялся стиль из value соответствующей ссылки?

Comment: очень странное использование ссылок, может Вам нужны все же опции?

Comment: согласен, что странное, но через ссылки я запускаю onclick и функцию для другого события

Comment: при нажатии на ссылку я через  onclick запускаю функцию и передаю значение ссылки в input. одновременно мне нужно, чтобы менялся background другого объекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более органичный вариант:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#colors > li > a').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor = e.dataset.color
  })
})
```

```css
div { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<ul id="colors">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" data-color="red">Красный</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" data-color="green">Зеленый</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" data-color="black">Черный</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div></div>
```

Подробнее о каждом из методов в MDN:

- [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

### Вариант `background-url`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#colors > li > a').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+e.dataset.url+')'
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul id="colors">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" data-url="https://searx.be/image_proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Fs1.qwant.com%2Fthumbr%2F474x266%2F0%2Fa%2F8ec2bb493e481fa1aa5a861d54a0173139c48d9ccf7ddbb49ce3088640d761%2Fth.jpg%3Fu%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftse2.mm.bing.net%252Fth%253Fid%253DOIP.U88J_cJjZbfpEGjWI3si7QHaEK%2526pid%253DApi%26q%3D0%26b%3D1%26p%3D0%26a%3D0&h=c1dc51277d999a2e0b061a1a68b94701ae438bb799133623dc9a987d39747577">Пример 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" data-url="https://searx.be/image_proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Fs1.qwant.com%2Fthumbr%2F474x355%2F9%2F2%2F3517b372fb7c98a987c337e3166db815585ef8825a801f35163027254ee703%2Fth.jpg%3Fu%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftse2.mm.bing.net%252Fth%253Fid%253DOIP.goVLhaQ_zulVVIEGy2Tx1AHaFj%2526pid%253DApi%26q%3D0%26b%3D1%26p%3D0%26a%3D0&h=7884882f5a9e045bcdc783c2196615bc00db1d89348b2b8bd13129408d519ab6">Пример 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" data-url="https://searx.be/image_proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com%2Ff%2Fb3be1dae-3caa-4d45-be6c-3de586ba95e2%2Fddx1e8m-26dd8f7d-e50d-4c9c-9b2e-fbdcf0447845.jpg%2Fv1%2Ffill%2Fw_622%2Ch_350%2Cq_70%2Cstrp%2Fview_by_bisbiswas_ddx1e8m-350t.jpg%3Ftoken%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9OTAwIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYjNiZTFkYWUtM2NhYS00ZDQ1LWJlNmMtM2RlNTg2YmE5NWUyXC9kZHgxZThtLTI2ZGQ4ZjdkLWU1MGQtNGM5Yy05YjJlLWZiZGNmMDQ0Nzg0NS5qcGciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9MTYwMCJ9XV0sImF1ZCI6WyJ1cm46c2VydmljZTppbWFnZS5vcGVyYXRpb25zIl19.22edUDfqyg5b02ua2mH1Rn4L5mfp1jncwxOnQo4uttc&h=3cd463763e84f7eb8e0c80cdb959bd9baaca8e71e69f712a43616b43cb79fb06">Пример 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div></div>
```

В некой "ячейке" сохранена ссылка и для каждого `a` есть событие клика, если пользователь нажмёт на элемент тогда из "ячейки" возмёться ссылка и будет использоваться для заднего фона.

Comment: а если мне нужно не цвет, а картинку фоном сделать? например, в качестве value я укажу ссылку на картинку и мне нужно, чтобы у объекта появился стиль background: url (значение value);

Comment: @АлександрЗинченко у меня не совсем как у вас реализовано, у меня вы можете заметить что цвет храниться в атрибуте который содержит `data-`, это значит что это некая ячейка для элемента в который можно хранить информацию, так вот, просто сделайте для каждой ссылки(тега `a`) такую ячейку, в который будете хранить ссылку, а дальше по такому же принципу, выберите стиль для вашего `background`-а, подробнее о стилях вы можете узнать по ссылке `HTMLElement.style`, которая также указана сверху, если хотите могу ответ отредактировать и написать как это сделать если по тексту непонятно.

Comment: Если Вы отредактируете код, это сильно ускорит процесс :) не силён в JS, но при выполнении проекта запнулся на этом моменте

Comment: @АлександрЗинченко готово, сделал пример того о чём я говорил, если возникнут вопросы, спрашивайте, не стесняйтесь.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё работает! :)

Answer (score 0):

Документация к изучению: [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) и [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

```html
<ul id="colors">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" onclick='document.getElementById("myElement").style.cssText="background-color: red;"'>Красный</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" onclick='document.getElementById("myElement").style.cssText="background-color: green;"'>Зеленый</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="back" onclick='document.getElementById("myElement").style.cssText="background-color: black;"'>Черный</a>
    </li>
</ul>

и есть объект:

<div id="myElement" style="width:100px; height: 100px;">hello</div>
```

Comment: А это специально сделано так ужасно?))